# How to pass string in android TimePicker

Tags: java, android, string, sms, timepicker

I have to pass hours and minutes into calendar.set method.

**My code:**

```
 String smsBody=getIntent().getExtras().getString("smsBody");
    String msg = smsBody.toString();
    String[] time = msg.split(":");
    String Hours = time[0];
    String Minutes = time[1];
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //The problem comes here

    //Hours
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());

    //Minutes
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Pass Hours and Minutes to the calendar ?

Comment: ya timepiker should get hour and minutes and set time in UI based on smsbody

Comment: What is the issue? Can you add more code? What is alarmTimePicker here? Elaborate more what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String smsBody=getIntent().getExtras().getString("smsBody");
String msg = smsBody.toString();
String[] time = msg.split(":");
int Hours = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
int Minutes = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);

alarmTimePicker.setCurrentHour(Hours);
alarmTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(Minutes);
```

Comment: Working fine. Thank you very much!!